# Using Datetime Vectors to Filter a Dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, lubridate

I am trying to filter a data frame using a vector of datetime objects (POSIXct). The first vector contains the start times and the second vector contains the end times. I want to return only values that fall within one of the datetime pairs, i.e., is between one pair of start and end times.

Here's some sample data:

```
dat <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1604386800, 1604386801, 
                                              1604386802, 1604386803,
                                              1604386804, 1604386805,
                                              1604473200, 1604473201,
                                              1604473202, 1604473203,
                                              1604473204, 1604473205,
                                              1604386800, 1604386801,
                                              1604386802, 1604386803,
                                              1604386804, 1604386805,
                                              1604473200, 1604473201,
                                              1604473202, 1604473203,
                                              1604473204, 1604473205,
                                              1604586800, 1604586801, 
                                              1604586802, 1604586803,
                                              1604586804, 1604586805,
                                              1604586800, 1604586801, 
                                              1604586802, 1604586803,
                                              1604586804, 1604586805),
                                            class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                                            tzone = "UTC"),
                      process_time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,5L, 0L, 1L, 2L,
                                       3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
                                       0L, 1L, 2L,3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L,
                                       3L, 4L,5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,5L),
                      process_name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                       "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
                                       "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                                       "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                       "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                       "A")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

And here's what I've got so far:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

start_time <- ymd_hms(c("2020-11-03 07:00:01", "2020-11-04 07:00:01",
                        "2020-11-05 14:33:21"))
end_time <- ymd_hms(c("2020-11-03 07:00:04", "2020-11-04 07:00:04",
                      "2020-11-05 14:33:24"))

filtered_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(date(timestamp), process_name) %>%
  filter(timestamp >= start_time & timestamp <= end_time)
```

What I am looking for is the first and last value being filtered out for each date and process type. It would look something like:

```
timestamp             |   process_time    |   process_name
------------------------------------------------------------
2020-11-03 07:00:01   |         1         |        A
2020-11-03 07:00:02   |         2         |        A
2020-11-03 07:00:03   |         3         |        A
2020-11-03 07:00:04   |         4         |        A

2020-11-04 07:00:01   |         1         |        A
2020-11-04 07:00:02   |         2         |        A
2020-11-04 07:00:03   |         3         |        A
2020-11-04 07:00:04   |         4         |        A

2020-11-03 07:00:01   |         1         |        B
2020-11-03 07:00:02   |         2         |        B
2020-11-03 07:00:03   |         3         |        B
2020-11-03 07:00:04   |         4         |        B
       ...                     ...                ...

#spacing added for clarity
```

What appears to be happening is the start and end time vectors are being recycled. So it compares the first row of the dataframe to the first items in the start and end time vectors, then the second row is compared to the second items in the start and end time vectors, and so on. Every few rows it does get a match.

What I need to happen is each row of the dataframe is compared to **all** three datetime pairs before moving onto the next row in the dataframe. It almost seems like `purrr` would be the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading up on `lubridate` we could use `intervals` for this purpose.
If there are multiple intervals then the documentation recommends we turn this into a list:

```
intervals <- list(interval(start_time, end_time))
```

Suppose we want to check if a certain date is within these intervals we can use the `%within%` function:

```
ts <- ymd_hms(2020-11-03 07:00:02)
ts %within% intervals
```

Results in:

```
> ts %within% intervals
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Or if we want to check all intervals at the same time:

```
> any(ts %within% intervals)
[1] TRUE
```

Applying this to your data frame:

```
dat <- dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(within = any(timestamp %within% intervals))
```

After which you can use simple filtering.

Comment: I was able to make this work by applying rowwise() prior to your suggested mutate. Without the rowwise, it seems to be flagging everything as TRUE. Is there a way to do it without calling rowwise?

Comment: My bad, `any(dat$timestamp %within% intervals)` returns `TRUE` and that result is recycled and that causes all rows to be `TRUE`. Indeed, using `rowwise` solves this. I updated the response. Thanks for this catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map2_lgl` from `purrr` to check if `any`  `timestamp` in each `date` is `between` `start_time` and `end_time`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  group_by(date = date(timestamp), process_name) %>%
  filter(any(map2_lgl(start_time, end_time, ~any(between(timestamp, .x, .y)))))
```